# How to solve opening & closing div bootstrap issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, handlebars.js

I'm rendering with handlebars a list of items and I'm using bootstrap to create a toggle `div` for every item. Handlebars works fine and also the toggle but not the closing-div function of bootstrap.

(I've already try to use bootstrap accordion but it was not working, so I would like solve the problem using `jQuery`)

Every time I open a new div it should close the other one (if there is one already open); This is not working, I can open more than one panel for time.

```
<section id="list-wrap">

  <script id="list-items" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each cards}}

      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading grad">
          <h4>
            <span class="title-style">{{name}}</span>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#{{this.code}}">
              <i class="chevron_toggleable indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right  pull-left"></i>
              </a>
            <p class="apr title-style"> {{apr}} % APR </p>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="{{this.code}}" class="changeClass panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div>
              <div class="img-div">
                <img src="assets/{{code}}.png">
              </div>
              <div class="info-div"><p class="info-paragraf">{{information}}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="cashback-div">
                <p class="cashback-paragraf-1">Cashback</p>
                <p class="cashback-paragraf-2">{{cashback}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    {{/each}}
  </script>

</section>
```

this was working until I added a express server:

```
$('i').click(function () {
  $('.changeClass').removeClass('in');
});
```

Comment: Solved. It was an asynchronous problem. The js function is working.

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery UIs accordion as an option.

You just have to put the items in an accordion tag, wrap each item in a div as a child of the accordion div and then call the accordion method on the accordion div.

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 1):

I would use a jquery accordion function like this one. **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Domt301/hntdv4a9/)**

```
 $('#accordion').accordion({
        collapsible:true,

    beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
         // The accordion believes a panel is being opened
        if (ui.newHeader[0]) {
            var currHeader  = ui.newHeader;
            var currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
         // The accordion believes a panel is being closed
        } else {
            var currHeader  = ui.oldHeader;
            var currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
        }
         // Since we've changed the default behavior, this detects the actual status
        var isPanelSelected = currHeader.attr('aria-selected') == 'true';

         // Toggle the panel's header
        currHeader.toggleClass('ui-corner-all',isPanelSelected).toggleClass('accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top',!isPanelSelected).attr('aria-selected',((!isPanelSelected).toString()));

        // Toggle the panel's icon
        currHeader.children('.ui-icon').toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-e',isPanelSelected).toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s',!isPanelSelected);

         // Toggle the panel's content
        currContent.toggleClass('accordion-content-active',!isPanelSelected)    
        if (isPanelSelected) { currContent.slideUp(); }  else { currContent.slideDown(); }

        return false; // Cancels the default action
    }
});
```